# Python script execution in a React.js App

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, youtube-data-api

I have a Python script that uploads videos to a specific YouTube channel and runs in terminal.

I also have a React.js App where I have a form in which I ask the client to provide me with video details such as the video title, description, tags, video file path, etc.

**My goal** is to have my React.js app run the Python script once the client hits the 'submit' button in the application after the form mentioned above is filled.

How can I call this Python script in a Javascript file based from React.js? Is it possible? If so, what would I need to do?

NOTE: A potential problem I see with this: having a browser-based app running scripts with a click of a button is quite unsafe...

Please Advise :)

Comment: Maybe expose your python script as a REST API, then on button click you do a request to execute that?

Comment: The video data will have to handled at the server level, cannot be called from frontend to python directly.